# Access to geometry inside QgsGeometryCollection PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometrycollection

I want to transform geometry in QGIS to QgsGeometry (for rubber band etc.).

```
    point = QgsPoint(1, 2)
    line = QgsLineString(QgsPoint(3, 4), QgsPoint(5, 6))
    poly = QgsPolygon(QgsLineString([QgsPoint(7, 8), QgsPoint(9, 0), QgsPoint(1, 0)]))
    g_col = QgsGeometryCollection()
    g_col.addGeometry(point)
    g_col.addGeometry(poly)

    print(QgsGeometry(line))
    for g in g_col:
        print(QgsGeometry(g))
```

This is example code, but idea is same.

My code works fine if I transform geometry not in geometry collection, but when I try to transform parts of geometry collection to QgsGeometry, QGIS crashes with not python error. But, before crash, code works fine, so I get in console all of my prints.

Also I tried to get geometry from collection by `childGeometry()` and `geometryN()` methods with same result.

What is my mistake? I guess, I missing some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [`clone()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometry.html#a6a916e15201499e34a64f2de7946188d) when doing `QgsGeometry(g)` like this `QgsGeometry(g.clone())` otherwise it indeed crashes.

This crash occurs because QGIS's  [`QgsAbstractGeometry`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometry.html) objects can't be shared (i.e. be part of a `QgsGeometryCollection` *and* the underlying geometry for a `QgsGeometry`). You did this by having both `g_col.addGeometry(g)` and `QgsGeometry(g)`.

```py
point = QgsPoint(1, 2)
line = QgsLineString(QgsPoint(3, 4), QgsPoint(5, 6))
poly = QgsPolygon(QgsLineString([QgsPoint(7, 8), QgsPoint(9, 0), QgsPoint(1, 0)]))
g_col = QgsGeometryCollection()
g_col.addGeometry(point)
g_col.addGeometry(poly)

print(QgsGeometry(line))
for g in g_col:
    print(QgsGeometry(g.clone()))
```

Comment: Thanks, i also found that solution. But what if i have big geometry?  What if i have polygon with 1000 points etc.?

Comment: It is really fast. To give you an idea, I have a polygon with over 500000 points, it takes 0.5ms to copy, (0.0005s). you can copy 2000 polygons this big every second. So for a polygon of "only" 1000 points, you can probably copy a few million every second.